# TextFile contains EOF. How to read to the real EOF?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, lotus-domino

I an fighting with a weird issue. First of all, I have no chance to change the way, the file is created; it is the vendors responsibility.

On a IBM Domino server, I create a response file for the command "tell traveler show user".
The file is a textfile. Under some circumstances ( see http://www.eknori.de/2017-02-05/fun-with-ibm-traveler-and-java/ for the full story ) the file contains a -1 character (EOF) in the middle of the file.

I have tried several ways to read the file ( BufferedReader, Scanner, InputStream, LineIterator and such ), but all of them check for -1 or null as an indicator for EOF.

I am running out of options. Does anybody have any idea, how to get the whole data from the file?

UPDATE:

Here is the content of the files created and what I get on the server console ( and in BufferedReader )

[image: All Good]

[image: Reading stopped]

There is no difference in the HEX, but the second one stops processing the file.

Comment: That's impossible. A byte is `0-255`, so there's no `-1` in the file. The `read()` method returns an int so it can return byte values and -1 to indicate EOF.

Comment: @Kayaman They're not bytes, they're chars. OP's blog post shows he is reading chars. But still: you should never be able to read a -1 char.

Comment: @Ulrich what is the actual byte data of the file around where you get the -1?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that this "tell traveler show user" command isn't finished writing its output when you start reading the output file, and the file actually ends after the "Replicas:" line when you're reading it.

Comment: have you tried `bufferedReader --> readLine()` method. it returns null if EOF

Comment: How is this "tell traveler show user" command invoked? Does your java program invoke it and then wait for it to finish? Could you [edit] your question to show or describe how you invoke this command and then read the file that it produces?

Comment: Well, what shall I say. You are absolutely right. I have build in a delay before I start reading the file. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: Suggestion - instead of just a delay, issue a "show server" (or some other command) after the "tell traveller" command and redirect it to a second file. When the second file exists, it will be safe to read the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you should try different encoding rather then default in that case `EOF` may be encountered as different character & your `FileInputStream` will not terminated at that point.
But doing so you have to convert that read text to the actual text using proper technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the stream into a byte[] array (or a ByteBuffer) and then the *read* method returns number of read bytes.

Regardless that - IMHO you should consider:

- when using the BufferedReader, the *readLine()* may return *null* at the end of the file, that's why you get the NullPointerException on the trim() method
- if you read bytes, they will have values of 0-255, but it doesn't mean you can convert them all into the text
- check the file size - maybe the file is really incomplete while you trying to read it and the file really ends there (read method returns value 0-255 for data or -1 for EOF), so the input stream really read the file until its end

Answer (score 0):

well "**bufferedreader**" works fine for your problem, just tried

```js
public class ee {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String  thisLine = "";
       try{
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/Users/rathi.ankush/Desktop/temp.txt")));
          while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(thisLine);
          }       
       }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the same code, that I used initially. Also, I have updated my post with the console output using your code.